# How to plot the graph using swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I tried to plot one graph using swift UI

- {x: [1,2,3,4,5], y: [1,2,3,4,5], x_lablel: 'Salary', y_label: 'exper'}
- Line is blue color
- Each point is red color with point marked and labelled

The parent folder have two files. LineChartView.swift and ContentView.swift

My LineChartView.swift file have below data

```
import SwiftUI
import Charts


struct LineChartRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    // Define any necessary properties for the chart view
    var dataPoints: [Double]
    var values: [Double]

    // Implement the required `makeUIView` function to create the UIKit view (LineChartView)
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> Charts.LineChartView {
        return Charts.LineChartView()
    }

    // Implement the required `updateUIView` function to update the view when SwiftUI changes
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: Charts.LineChartView, context: Context) {
        // ...
        let entries = zip(dataPoints, values).map { Charts.ChartDataEntry(x: $0, y: $1) }
        let dataSet = Charts.LineChartDataSet(entries: entries, label: "Line Chart Data")
        dataSet.colors = [UIColor.blue] // Customize the line color
        dataSet.circleColors = [UIColor.blue] // Customize the circle color

        let data = Charts.LineChartData(dataSet: dataSet)

        uiView.data = data
        uiView.notifyDataSetChanged()
        // ...
    }
}
```

My ContentView.swift file have below data

```
import SwiftUI
import Charts


struct ContentView: View {
    let xValues: [Double] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    let yValues: [Double] = [10, 20, 15, 25, 18, 30, 22]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Use the LineChartRepresentable view and pass the data points to create the chart
            LineChartRepresentable(dataPoints: xValues, values: yValues)
                .frame(height: 300) // Set the desired height of the chart view
        }
    }
}
```

Below are errors

```
Type 'LineChartRepresentable' does not conform to protocol 'UIViewRepresentable' (Line 5)
No type named 'LineChartView' in module 'Charts'(Line 11)
No type named 'LineChartView' in module 'Charts' (Line 16)
Module 'Charts' has no member named 'ChartDataEntry' (Line 18)
Module 'Charts' has no member named 'LineChartDataSet'(Line 19)
Module 'Charts' has no member named 'LineChartData'(Line 23)
```

Comment: There is indeed no `LineChartView` in the Charts library. What makes you think it exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an `Identifiable` struct to represent your data, rather than two random arrays. You could turn the two arrays into a struct like this:

```
struct DataPoint : Identifiable{
    let x: Double
    let y: Double
    let id: Int
}
```

The `id` could be the index of that data point in the array:

```
let dataPoints = zip(x, y).enumerated().map { (i, pair) in
    DataPoint(x: pair.0, y: pair.1, id: i)
}
```

Then you can make a `Chart` like this:

```
// in your view's body property...
Chart(dataPoints) { point in
    LineMark(x: .value("Salary", point.x), y: .value("Exper", point.x))
        .foregroundStyle(.blue)
    PointMark(x: .value("Salary", point.x), y: .value("Exper", point.x))
        .foregroundStyle(.red)
        // here I'm labelling each point with the y value
        .annotation(
            position: .top,
            alignment: .bottom,
            spacing: 10
        ) {
            Text("\(point.y, format: .number)")
        }
}
.chartXAxisLabel("Salary")
.chartYAxisLabel("Exper")
```